# Trying to make stamina go down as timer goes up. I want it to go down by 2 every 10 seconds

Tags: java

Idea was that as the timer goes up by plus one, the code checks if it is a value of 10 so that every 10 seconds, strength depletes by -2.. instead timer begins at 11 and strength is automatically 0.

public void simpleTimer(){ //creates a timer

```
timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){ 
   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          second++;
          counterLabel.setText("" + second); //displays the time increasing
       
         
        while(player.strength > 0){
         
            if (second % 10 == 0)
            {
            player.strength = player.strength - 2; //sets new player strength
            StrengthLabelNumber.setText("" + player.strength);
           
            }
            else if (second % 10 != 0)
            {
            second++;
```

Comment: It would help if you show what you have done.  Preferably in a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain how this will fit into your design but here is one way to schedule a countDown timer.

First, create a class that subclasses TimerTask.

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask {
     int strength;
     int decrement;

     public MyTask(int initialStrength, int decrement) {
         this.strength = initialStrength;
         this.decrement = decrement;
     }

     public void run() {
         strength -= decrement;
         System.out.println(strength);
     }

     public int getStrength() {
          return strength;
     }
 }
```

The you can start a Timer supplying the task, initial delay, and duration.  Here the duration is 2 seconds.

```
Timer t = new Timer("MyTimer");
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(1000, 2);
t.schedule(myTask, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
```

prints every two seconds

```
98
96
94
92
90
88
```

**Updated**

Here is a simple program that simply counts down the timer in a small timer panel.  When the mouse is clicked over the larger panel it simply stores the current location of the mouse and the stamina value in a list as a `Loc` record and then resets stamina to `100`.  Repaint then causes the values to be displayed in the main panel.  I can't really help you integrate a timer into your project as yours is much more complicated. But this does show how to manipulate a timer in a Swing environment.  I hope it helps.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SimpleDemo extends JPanel {

    int height = 500;
    int width = 500;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);

    record Loc(int x, int y, int stamina) {
    }

    List<Loc> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SimpleDemo());

    }

    public JFrame f = new JFrame();
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width,height);
    }
    public SimpleDemo() {
        addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
        f.add(this);
        
        setBackground(Color.white);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();

        // center frame in screen
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        startTimer(milli);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

  
    int milli = 500; // seconds in milliseconds
    int stamina = 100;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g = g.create();
        g.setFont(font);
        for (Loc loc : locations) {
            g.drawString(loc.stamina + "", loc.x, loc.y);
        }
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void startTimer(int milli) {

        JPanel timerPanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g = g.create();
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setFont(font);
                g.drawString(stamina + "", 0, 20);
                g.dispose();
            }
        };

        timerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 20));
        this.add(timerPanel);
        Timer t = new Timer(0, (ae) -> {
            repaint();
            stamina -= 2;

        });
        t.setDelay(milli);
        t.start();
    }

    class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            locations.add(new Loc(me.getX(),me.getY(), stamina));
            stamina = 100;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try implementing this and see if I can get it to fit into my code :)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Is there a way I can message you on another platform? I have no way to send you my code on here

Comment: Can you post a small [mre] of what you are trying to do?  Just update your question with the code.

Comment: I've done it, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: The Swing timer is meant to be used in conjunction with other Swing components (e.g. JFrame, JPanel, etc).  If you try and run it in a non-swing environment it will just time out  and the program will exit.  Then the other method in my answer should be used.  Also, to see what problems you are having I need a complete, but small program that compiles and demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I am using jframe and jpanel as well for my code. Its part of my user interface. I'm not sure how I could send you my program as it is huge. Around 12 classes in total. The issue is when it runs, the timer begins on 11 and strength is already at 0. If I add your method, do I add it below that code I have sent?

Comment: If you can provide more about the text based game, objective, and how stamina is used I will see if I can provide more help.

Comment: So the game is you begin in a forest and have to navigate round using the 4 options given each time you choose. I.e go north, east, south, or west. The stamina depletes by -2 in order to make the game harder. So you only have a certain amount of time to complete it. I was hoping to bring stamina potions into it as well as different environments depleting stamina by more. That's if I can figure out this first hurdle though. Do you need me to send the other classes such as my main class and my UI class?

Comment: I have just managed to get it working!! 2 hours of messing with the code and it finally works. Thank you for all of your help :)

Comment: @LaurenMillar Congrats!  And I bet you learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you focus on the *stamina* level rather than on accumulating time count. The *stamina* level is what drives your game really, not elapsed time. And I imagine your game might eventually gain a feature where *stamina* can increase as well as decrease.

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

A [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) can run a task after a specified amount of time elapses.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors. newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

Define your task as implementing  `Runnable` or `Callable`. That task would do *three* things, after checking that we have some remaining *stamina*:

- Decrement the *stamina* level kept in an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).
- Call back to the user-interface to note the change in *stamina* status. GUI frameworks such as Vaadin, JavaFX, and Swing offer a hook for thread-safe callbacks.
- Reschedule itself with the scheduled executor service.

Be sure to eventually shut down your executor service before your app ends. See boilerplate code given on Javadoc for [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

### Example code

Our task class.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator;

public class StaminaWaning implements Runnable
{
    private final AtomicInteger stamina;
    private final Duration duration;

    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses;
    private final IntUnaryOperator unaryOperatorSubtraction = ( int x ) -> ( x - 2 );

    public StaminaWaning ( final AtomicInteger stamina , final Duration interval , final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService )
    {
        this.stamina = stamina;
        this.duration = interval;

        this.ses = scheduledExecutorService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        int remainingStamina = this.stamina.updateAndGet( this.unaryOperatorSubtraction );
        System.out.println( "Stamina reduced to " + remainingStamina + " at " + Instant.now() );
        // … make thread-safe callback to UI …
        if ( remainingStamina > 0 )
        {
            // Still alive, continuing the game, so schedule this task to continue waning of stamina.
            this.ses.schedule( this , this.duration.toNanos() , TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        }
    }
}
```

And our app that instantiates and runs that task.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Game
{
    private final AtomicInteger stamina;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses;

    public Game ( )
    {
        this.stamina = new AtomicInteger( 100 );
        this.ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "stamina = " + stamina + " at " + Instant.now() );

        Runnable staminaWaning = new StaminaWaning( this.stamina , Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ) , this.ses );
        this.ses.schedule( staminaWaning , 10 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); // Get the task started running. It will then schedule itself for further runs.
        // … other stuff happening … we simulate by sleeping this main thread
        try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMinutes( 10 ).toMillis() ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        // then app ends
        if ( ! this.ses.isShutdown() )
        {
            this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination( this.ses );
        }
        System.out.println( "Done running `demo`. " + Instant.now() );
    }

    private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( ExecutorService executorService )
    {
        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
        try
        {
            // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                { System.err.println( "Executor service did not terminate. " + Instant.now() ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            executorService.shutdownNow();
            // Preserve interrupt status
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
stamina = 100 at 2023-01-06T23:15:03.663213Z
Stamina reduced to 98 at 2023-01-06T23:15:13.676322Z
Stamina reduced to 96 at 2023-01-06T23:15:23.687932Z
Stamina reduced to 94 at 2023-01-06T23:15:33.694538Z
Stamina reduced to 92 at 2023-01-06T23:15:43.700024Z
…
Stamina reduced to 10 at 2023-01-06T23:22:33.874121Z
Stamina reduced to 8 at 2023-01-06T23:22:43.875564Z
Stamina reduced to 6 at 2023-01-06T23:22:53.878463Z
Stamina reduced to 4 at 2023-01-06T23:23:03.884400Z
Stamina reduced to 2 at 2023-01-06T23:23:13.887652Z
Stamina reduced to 0 at 2023-01-06T23:23:23.889939Z
Done running `demo`. 2023-01-06T23:25:03.680419Z
```